# Using regex to match on pairs

Tags: regex, perl, matching, flex-lexer

I want to write a regular expression that will match on the following:

```
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4
C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
```

HOWEVER

I'd like to do this in an elegant fashion besides just matching on the text exactly as it is - `c1[ ](to|through)[ ]c2[ ][,][ ]c2[ ](to|through)[ ]c3` etc.

This is for a lexer and it's written in lexx/yacc Regex. The scanner is Flex++. I want to match on pairs in increments of 1, but no less than 4 and no more than 7.

For the record, I've searched through other posts extensively and even asked a few folks. No ideas thus far.

Comment: Pardon my slow wit, but could you formulate it better, maybe with an example of input and expected result. Do you mean matching `Cn ... C(n+1)`?

Comment: Hi there. The input is exactly what you see above. The text is any of those phrases/lines above - c1 to c2 , c2 to c3 , etc. So yes, I do mean c(n+1). When I say no less than four, I mean I want no less than 4 combinations of the letter C plus a number, as in C1, C2, C3, and C4. Sorry it was unclear! I am new at this.

Comment: (1) Are you using Perl, or Perl Compatible Regexes (PCRE)? The first case has an elegant solution with embedded code. (2) Are you sure that this functionality should be in the *lexer*? Usually the lexer just finds simple tokens (preferably in linear time), which the parser then combines to an AST. Once a part is fully parsed, one would do *semantic validation*. E.g. for a tokenizer, the C code `( foo--bar }` might look OK, but a parser would barf. Likewise, a parser might accept `int foo = bar + 2`, but semantic validation would complain that `bar` is undeclared.

Comment: Ok so it's not Perl or PCRE. It's Lex/YACC regex. Sorry for the confusion. It sounds like what I'm trying to do just can't be done with regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you really are using lex/yacc (or flex/bison), you'll have to use both in conjunction.  Excuse my rusty syntax.

Flex:

```
"C"[0-9]+  { yylval->num = atoi(yytext+1); return TOKEN_CNUM; }   
"to"       { return TOKEN_TO;      }
"through"  { return TOKEN_TO;      }
","        { return TOKEN_COMMA;   }   
[\n\r]     { return TOKEN_NEWLINE; }
```

Bison:

```
line: pair "," pair "," pair "," pair              {assert($1+1 == $3); assert($3+1 == $5); assert($5+1 == $7); }
    | pair "," pair "," pair "," pair "," pair     { /* similar */ }
    | /* for 6 pairs */
    | /* for 7 pairs */
    ;   

pair: TOKEN_CNUM TOKEN_TO TOKEN_CNUM { assert($1+1 == $3); $$ = $3; }                                                 
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The numerical values on has to check oneself, for context depending "semantical" correctness.

```
^c\d+[ ](to|through)[ ]c\d+[ ]([,][ ]c\d+[ ](to|through)[ ]c\d+)*$
```

That would need additional processing.

In principle you could work with

```
^c\d+[ ](to|through)[ ]((c\d+),\3 ...)*c\d+$
        1          1   23    3  ^    2
```

That would state: the third group (here) `(c\d+)` must repeat after the comma `\3`.

Comment: Ok I will take this and see what I can do. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

```
 my $pairRE = qr/          # Start regular expression
                 \s*       # zero or more spaces
                 C         # 'C'
                 \d+       # one or more digits
                 \s+       # one or more spaces
                 (         # Start group
                   to        # 'to'
                   |         # or
                   through   # 'through'
                 )         # End group
                 \s+       # one or more spaces
                 C         # 'C'
                 \d+       # one or more digits
                 \s*       # zero or more spaces
                /x;        # End regular expression, eXtended syntax

  while (<DATA>) {
      print
        if /               # Start regular expression
            ^              # Start of line
            $pairRE        # a pair
            (              # Start group
             ,               # ','
             $pairRE         # a pair
            ){3,6}         # End group - match 3 to 6 copies of this group
           /x              # End regular expression, eXtended syntax
  }

__DATA__
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4
C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
```

Prints

```
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6
C1 to C2 , C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5
C2 to C3 , C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
C3 to C4 , C4 to C5 , C5 to C6 , C6 to C7
```

Comment: This looks pretty interesting. Not sure if I can implement it but I will see. Thank you!